# Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I develop method of login in my website, but i have problem in **login.controller.js**
I have this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined .
>       at login.controller.js:35

```
'use strict';

export default class LoginController {
  user = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };
  errors = {
    login: undefined
  };
  submitted = false;


  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor(Auth, $state) {
    this.Auth = Auth;
    this.$state = $state;
  }

  login(form) {
    this.submitted = true;

    if(form.$valid) {
      this.Auth.login({
        email: this.user.email,
        password: this.user.password,
        rememberme: this.user.remember
      })
        .then(() => {
          // Logged in, redirect to home
          this.$state.go('main');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.errors.other = err.message;
        });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please note: The tag angularjs is only for angular 1.x. For rest, it is angular

Comment: @Rakesh Burbure thank's, but you can help me to develop method for remember me in signin

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class LoginController {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor(Auth, $state) {
    this.Auth = Auth;
    this.$state = $state;
    this.user = {
      name: null,
      email: null,
      password: null
    };
    this.errors = {
      login: null,
      others: null // This was needed;
    };
    this.submitted = false;
  }

  login(form) {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (form.$valid) {
      this.Auth.login({
        email: this.user.email,
        password: this.user.password,
        rememberme: this.user.remember
      })
      .then(() => {
        return this.$state.go('main');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err); // see what 'err' looks like here
        this.errors.other = err.message;
      })
      .finally(() => {
        // Logged in, redirect to home
        console.log('last thing');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I moved your variables into the constructor. Put a console.log in to see what err looks like. It's possible 'message' simply does not exist on err. Also this.errors.others needed to be declared.

Comment: this error in console:TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at login.controller.js:35
    at processQueue (angular.js:17051)
    at angular.js:17095
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18233)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18531)
    at done (angular.js:12547)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12785)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12702) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"

Comment: I've updated it to use catch/finally, see if that clears it up.

Comment: @ rrd thank's, but i change something methods, because my initial problem the remember me not work with user login in my website